# Apache common's website

Tags: content-management-system

I am trying to develop an api, I would like to put up a website similar to apache common lang's.

Is there any open source website can use for this just like wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Common Lang use maven-site-plugin.
If you project use maven, check out this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/

Comment: Thanks! Do I actually create a new maven site project, or do I specify a maven goal on my existing maven project?

Comment: You can simply run 'maven site' to generate the website. You have to configure the content. I suggest you to read this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html.